# Looking for POwershell script for Intune/ Microsoft Graph to pull last user login , fields dont appear to exist

Tags: azure, powershell, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

We have a current export request to pull a csv of last logged user to any managed devices with Intune. Currently using the Microsoft Graph Powershell but the fields I require don't appear to exist.

Currently been trying

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Select-Object devicename, usersLoggedOn | export-csv -Path C:\Users\aaustin\Desktop\Enable.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

and

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Select-Object displayname, approximateLastLogonTimeStamp | export-csv -Path C:\Users\aaustin\Desktop\Enable.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Not 100% if there is any value held within intune to pull the last logged on user with a time stamp.
I know I can pull the current details of the device and who managed the device but cannot get current last login of user with time if possible

Comment: Here's a list of all of the properties which `Get-IntuneManagedDevice` can return.  I don't see properties like `approximateLastLogonTimeStamp` or anything else you were looking for.  The property you want *has to exist*, and I don't know that Intune would collect logon times (Devices don't sync with MDM that often)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#optional-query-parameters

InTune only syncs roughly every 8 hours...https://www.scconfigmgr.com/2015/09/29/policy-refresh-intervals-for-devices-managed-by-microsoft-intune/

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for specifically is `Get-AzureADDevice`

find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddevice?view=azureadps-2.0)

Specifically if you're looking to get a list of all devices as well as their last logon time you're looking for two specific parameters: `displayname` and `approximateLastLogonTimeStamp`

These will, when targetting against all devices grab the device name and the time it was last logged in, when connected to Azure AD you could write something like

```
Get-AzureADDevice -All 1 -Filter "startswith(DeviceOSType,'Windows')" | select objectID, deviceID, displayname, approximateLastLogonTimeStamp | export-csv -path 'path' -NoTypeInformation
```

this will grab all devices within an Azure Domain which are window devices, it'll grab object + device ID as well as the two main fields.

Example output:

```
ObjectId                             DeviceId                             DisplayName                                   ApproximateLastLogonTimeStamp
--------                             --------                             -----------                                   -----------------------------
1234-5678-9012-1234-1234-1234-1234-1 1234-5678-9012-1234-1234-1234-1234-1 Host Name                                     01/01/2020 10:18:26
```